# windows phone 8 sdk certificates expired

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, installation, certificate, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have tried to install wp8 sdk on my windows 8 laptop, but everytime I try to do so, the installation stops with an error saying that some of the certificates expired. Then the installation crashes and I need to start it again. I have already tried multiple ways of reinstalling SDK even following Microsoft's advice to install and run the following files from the download folder:

Download the Win8SharedSDKTools.msi package and install it.
Download the Windows_SDK/69661e20556b3ca9456b946c2c881ddd.cab package
Download the Windows_SDK/e072b3b3d3164e26b63338dce51862a7.cab package
Download the Windows_SDK/e3d1b35aecfccda1b4af6fe5988ac4be.cab package

But this issue with certificates continues to come up.

Is there any way of overcoming this problem?
What is wrong with these certificates and what these certificates stand for?
Is there a problem with my laptop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I know so far is changing the date of your computer back to June before launching the installation. Once the SDK is installed, you can switch your system back to the current date.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Change the date August 1 and install the windows SDK. once you successfully installed the vs you can change your date. this is the only problem.